Custom annotation on a bean that implements an interface
Context:

spring boot: 3.3.1
spring cloud: 2023.0.2

I am trying to make a custom annotation having something like this:
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Configuration
public class AspectJConfig {
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ServiceEvent {
}


@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class ServiceEventMethodAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(ServiceEvent)")
    public Object handleMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            log.info("Service event called");
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

Now, I have 2 components:
@Component
public class TestServiceEvent {

    @ServiceEvent
    public String duplicate(String x) {
        return x;
    }
}

And the second one:
public interface DummyInterface {
}

@Component
public class TestDummyServiceEvent implements DummyInterface {

    @ServiceEvent
    public String duplicate(String x) {
        return x;
    }
}

In pom.xml I added a dependency on spring-boot-starter-aop so aspectjweaver is also in the classpath.
First one is called, second one is not. I suspect it is around implementing the interface and having different type of proxies (JDK vs CGLIB) but I failed to find any documentation which treats differently (from my code POV) these objects. Is there anyone who can point me on what I am doing wrong here?
Update - I tried with both true/false for proxyTargetClass in @EnableAspectJAutoProxy.
Update #2 - as suggested, I am going to add also the way my methods are called. In general, everything is handled by spring (except pojos) so normally this should not be an issue.
@Slf4j
@RestController("testController")
public class TestClass implements TestApi {
    @Autowired
    private final TestDummyServiceEvent testDummyServiceEvent;
    
    @Autowired
    private final TestServiceEvent testServiceEvent;

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        log.info("First call:");
        testDummyServiceEvent.duplicate("a");

        log.info("Second call:");
        testServiceEvent.duplicate("b");

        log.info("The end.");
    }
}

Normally, in this call, I would expect to see twice in the logs "Service event called". I know which one is called because I can put a breakpoint there. It is true, I should have logged the output and it would have made it easier to trace.
Also - in case it matters - my intellij can spot the 'bad' one. The annotated method of the class that does not inherit an interface gets the "m" mark and you can use it to navigate to the a aspect method.

Thanks for all the details, but the problem probably is in the code you did not show here, e.g. in the way both components' methods are called. Please specify, or simply publish a minimal project on GitHub and link to it.

I updated it. Thanks for the heads up! It just simple rest controller on which I autowire both beans and then call directly like above.

Your code works flawlessly here. Like I said, please publish an MCVE on GitHub. I cannot reproduce your problem. It was super tedious already to copy & paste all your sample code, determine the imports, add a missing interface class, select package names etc. BTW, IntelliJ does not flag anything either: https://i.sstatic.net/26ubJ6VM.png

Sorry for the late reply (and for missing POC), I was off with limited access to net. I see there in your screenshot that you have the 2 methods. I did a small POC with nothing but spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-devtools, lombok and aspectjrt and, indeed, it works. On my real service, I only see one method if I click on that icon (where you have 2).

Well, I am using your exact code. If that does not reproduce the problem, the best way to create an MCVE is to use your own project, delete and shave off as much as possible step by step until you arrive at a minimal reproducer. In doing so, chances are you are learning enough about your own problem to solve it yourself. Otherwise, I  can try to help you, which probably will be pretty easy with a reproducer. BTW, I do not need your original classes, you can rename them and the methods, anonymise and "dummify" them so as not to violate any confidentiality rules.

Thanks. It's a biggish (and old) project so this would be difficult to achieve. I just bumped up dependencies to get them as much as possible up to date and add some new features. I am starting to wonder if it has anything to do with weavers or something in this area (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html#aop-aj-ltw). I will keep digging and if I get to a conclusion, I will update this question.

Actually, I never understood why so many developers claim that distilling a big project into an MCVE would be difficult. I even think it is a rather mechanical, almost trivial process. It is not a big technical challenge to iteratively cut off slices from a big project. It is much more difficult to build a big project from many modules than to shrink it to the bare minimum reproducing a problem: Cut off a chunk. If it still reproduces the problem cut off more, otherwise revert and cut off less or something else.
